# Burninate the [actual] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

May I suggest that the [actual](/questions/tagged/actual) tag be burninated? As it [stands now](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/actual), it is used to tag almost any question that contains the word "actual".  It's really useless, in my opinion.

Comment: I'm actually laughing out loud at this (the use, not your request).

Comment: @Jamal Probably someone really desperate to get one of the tag related badges.

Comment: @DennisMeng: I know, right?  Good thing it didn't get high enough for Taxonomist.

Comment: @Jamal Yep! That was my reaction too, together with a big slap on my forehead! :-)

Comment: BTW, nice to have a [burninate-request] meta-tag! Didn't notice it. :-)

Comment: I think it was created for situations like these. ;-) Must be quite common.

Comment: @Jamal Well, I count at least 4 burn requests under "top questions", so I'd assume so.

Comment: So what's the [actual] status on this [burninate-request] ? :D

Comment: @CSᵠ: I'm ashamed of myself for not suggesting the title be "Should [actual] receive an actual burnination?"

Comment: @CSᵠ I suppose [status-actually-burninated] :D

Comment: @Jamal: that should have been the [actual] title for this post! great thinking [rofl]